# Visual Studio 2010 cannot find SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 and I already have Visual Studio 2010.

When I try to connect to the SQL Server there exists no server on my `Add Connection` while my database engine works properly.

Why is that so?

Comment: It doesn't exist or you haven't added it yet? Just because you installed it doesn't mean it's going to magically show up in all your server lists...

Comment: could u please tell me how to do that actually?

Comment: I provided my answer below. Try it out and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that is VS 2010, you need to type in your localhost instead of choosing the connection from the drop-down list. I hope this issue is resolved in the next releases.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, in Server Explorer, you need to click the "Connect to Database" toolbar icon (or right-click Data Connections and choose "Add Connection...").

From the Data source list, choose Microsoft SQL Server and then click Continue. The Add Connection dialog box displays so you can enter your server name (machinename\instancename). You can choose between Windows or SQL Server Authentication (depends on how you set it up, but Windows Authentication should work for a local installation).

Once you have entered a correct server name and credentials you'll get a list of databases to choose. Select one if you wish and click OK. That should get your server added to the list for Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if from VB 2010 you go to Project >> Add New Item and choose the appropiate path for your server it should work.

You may also want to try Data >> Add New Data Source